# Bug in next and previous buttons in scroll gallery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, gallery

Im developing a horizontal scroll gallery for my website. So far I have the scroll function working fine with full screen, variable width images.

The next thing I've been looking to implement is next/prev buttons to slide between the images. I found a post on here that showed a solution with jQuery ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPF6F/26/)) which I have managed to implement into mine but with the issue that the next button only works for one image.

Here is my test page to show you what i mean: http://blackecho.co.uk/test-scroll/scroll-test(img).html

When I click next, it will scroll to the next image, but will only work once. You have to manually scroll forward a little bit for the button to work again. The other thing is that the previous button works fine!

After lots of testing, I'm struggling to find what it is that I have changed/added that has stopped it working.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <div id="t-scroll_container" >
    <div id="t-scroll">
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/a.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/8.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/a.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/b.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/d.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/c.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/e.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/10.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/9.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>
        <div class="t-pic_wrap"><img src="../assets/1.jpg" class="t-pic"></div>                      
   </div>
 </div>


<div style="position:fixed; bottom:1px;">
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#t-scroll_container{
 margin:0px;
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0;
 bottom:50px;
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

#t-scroll{
height:100%; 
overflow:auto;
white-space:nowrap;

}

.t-pic_wrap{
height:98%;
white-space:nowrap;
display:inline-block;

}

.t-pic{
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

JAVA

```
var currentElement = $("#t-scroll > div:nth-child(2)");
var onScroll = function () {
//get the current element
var container = $("#t-scroll");
var children = container.children();
var position = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = $(children[i]);
    var childLeft = container.offset().left < child.offset().left;
    if (childLeft) {
        currentElement = child;
        console.log(currentElement)
        return;
    }
}
}

var scrollToElement = function ($element) {
var container = $("#t-scroll");
var children = container.children();
var width = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = $(children[i]);
    if (child.get(0) == $element.get(0)) {
        if (i == 0) {
            width = 0;
        }
        container.animate({
            scrollLeft: width
        }, 200);
        onScroll();
    }
    if (child.next().length > 0) {
        //make sure we factor in borders/padding/margin in height
        width += child.next().offset().left - child.offset().left
    } else {
        width += child.width();
    }
}
}

var next = function (e) {
scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

var prev = function (e) {
var container = $("#t-scroll");
if (currentElement.prev().length > 0) {
    if (container.offset().left == currentElement.prev().offset().left) {
        currentElement = currentElement.prev().prev().length > 0 ?    currentElement.prev().prev() : currentElement.prev();
    }
    else {
        currentElement = currentElement.prev();
    }
}
scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

$("#t-scroll").scroll(onScroll);
$("#next").click(next);
$("#prev").click(prev);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, trouble in your css file :

if you will remove

```
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Geosans Light, sans-serif;
```

line - all should work. At least, it works fine here (i commented css line):

http://jsfiddle.net/nPF6F/29/

Comment: It's working! I haven't a clue why that broke the behaviour, i'd love to know how you figured it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, @Joe  :) Vote up please my answer and set it as a solution if my info was help. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is - you did not change currentElement during next function. And when you click again - currentElement is the same.

Comment: Sorry to be so clueless, but I'm not the best with jQuery. Im not 100% sure what I'm meant to be changing/adding. The main reason I'm confused if because I pretty much copied the code from the other post (minus the scrollToIndex function) yet mine is failing to function the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nPF6F/27/ - copy of your page, excluding your additional js file references and js code injects. Works like a charm. Trouble in your additional js files or js. Try to remove part by part all other js's and other codes and you will find what code broke your behaviour.

Comment: Ive updated the test page http://blackecho.co.uk/test-scroll/scroll-test(img).html, made sure all the java script was the same as yours and then striped down the whole page until it was pretty much the same as what was in the fiddle (except for my stylesheet link, and the link to the jQuery library), and yet it's still broken. Could one of my other styles be causing an issue?

Comment: I detect, that trouble in your css file. If you will change css content to http://jsfiddle.net/nPF6F/28/ - should work. Hm. it is strange :)